# Первые вопросы по Android

Tags: android

День добрый! Решил расширить сферу с веб-программирования до разработки мобильных приложений. Всё сделал, всё установил, всё работает, но как обычно встречаются спорные моменты.

1) У меня в главном окне, есть объект editText1, почему при запуске приложения на реальном девайсе у меня сразу запускается клавиатура, а на виртуалке, всё норм? Как сделать чтоб на риал дивайс, всё было норм, и клава не запускалась при старте?

2) Почему при перевороте девайса низ обрезается? Как сделать чтобы можно было скролить когда меняется ориентация?

3) И почему во вкладке Custom & Library View пусто? Что там должно быть и как добавить?

4) Как сделать картинки кликабельными? Чтобы при нажатии он отправлял на определённый адрес УРЛ. Ну вобщем как сделать баннеры? И как их лучше сделать, чтобы можно было менять, не прибегая к редактированию кода и перекомпиляции приложения (используя веб)?

Пока, всё!

Comment: Зевает - yawns

Comment: на эмуляторе не выскакивает - там есть виртуальная клавиатура:)

Answer (score 4):

1) Да фиг его знает почему - на эмуляторе действительно не выскакивает, а не девайсе выскакивает. Никогда не пытался этим себя заморочить и всегда ориентировался на поведение реального девайса. Убрать клаву можно миллионом способов. Самый простой и надежный - это указать нужный тип `InputType` для `EditText` (в зависимости от `InputType` ось и выдает нужную клаву) - чтобы убрать надо задать:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Другой способ это убрать фокус ввода с виджета (не очень надежно). Есть и третий способ:

```
InputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

2) Надо поместить виджет в `ScrollView`

3) Хз... - это ваши идешные дела

4) Посмотри в сторону `View.setOnClickListener`